# iPhone App closes automatically with no error

Tags: iphone

I wrote an app which doesn't run in background mode.
The first time I deploy it in the simulator, it works correctly (except when the Mac has his time) and fine. When I press "Home Button" or if I exit with exit(0), and then launch again the App, the sim goes tfu and quit from the App with no error or warnings...
Some help?

Note that may help: The Application uses core Data.

EDIT:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
self.ingredientiPizza = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

[window addSubview:loader.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

EDIT 2: Stack Trace

> objc_msgSend
>   ??
>   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
>   -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
>   _UIApplicationHandleEvent
>   PurpleEventCallback
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   __CFRunLoopDoSource1
>   __CFRunLoopRun
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   CFRunLoopRunInMode
>   -[UIApplication _run]
>   UIApplicationMain
>   in main at main.m:14

Comment: post some sample code for example your applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Honestly I don't know what to post exactly, because I don't know where errors can be.

Comment: I suspect the self.ingredientiPizza has been dealloc'ed!  Not the right place really for this.  I wouldn't go placing items like that in your app delegate.  Read up on MVC

Comment: I've analyzed with the debugger the situation. I could track down some indications. It's a EXC_BAD_ACCESS that happens if I restart the program. I'll post the stack trace.

Comment: The crash happens after viewDidAppear, is it possible to see the ViewController just for a bit.

Comment: Then show us the `viewDidAppear` method please. ;)

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [self.view becomeFirstResponder];
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

Comment: There are no problem with tests on the device... I'm getting tired...